# Is there any way to connect a dictionary to a pdf reader in linux?

Tags: dictionary, pdf, thesaurus, okular

I am reading some pdf books in English, and sometimes I need to look up a word in dictionary. I have goldendict on my system. And I use okular as my pdf reader.
My question is that is there any way to connect goldendict (or any other dictionary that may work) to my pdf reader? So that if I select the word, I can look it up directly from the pdf reader? (Some apps in android have this feature.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note for Others

The ability to run Golden Dictionary from Okular should be working.

For an insight see https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict/issues/1378

Comment: Thanks alot, this was completely what I was looking for. Thanks again